# Finding the remainder of $\overbrace{11\ldots1}^{123 \text{ times}}$ divided by $271$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

When a $\overbrace{11\ldots1}^{123 \text{ times}}$ is divided by $271$, what is the remainder?

I don't know how could I proceed because the number is too big to divide and I can't even factor it out. Please someone let me know how to solve these kind of problems, also if there is any shortcut related to these kinda problems please let me know.

Comment: Hint: $271\times 41$

Comment: Are you sure the modulus is 271? That's a very 'random' value for this sort of thing.  That said, the number is $(10^{123}-1)/9$, and you can evaluate $10^{123}\bmod 271$ in only a few dozen operations, and $\frac19$ in not too many more...

Comment: Sorry this is all going over my head and the remainder I am looking for is 111

Comment: To make Henry's hint more clear : $271\cdot 41=11111$, so the number $1\cdots 1$ with $120$ ones is divisble by $271$. The rest should be trivial.

Comment: Why only 271x41 and how does it prove that it divides 111..1 120 times

Comment: We have $24$ five-groups of ones and $11111$ ($5$ ones) is divisble by $271$.

Comment: Awesome @peter but how could you guys figure out the fact that 271x41 would be 11111?

Comment: @peter could you explain it better

Comment: Sorry, I meant the order of $10$ modulo $271$. It is the smallest number $o$ with $10^o\equiv 1\mod 271$. (Since $271$ is a prime, the order must be a divisor of $271-1=270$ because of Fermat's little theorem). We get $o=5$, therefore $271|10^5-1$

Comment: We can conclude further that $271|(10^5-1)/9$ because of $gcd(271,9)=1$. So we have $271|11111$ . This easily implies $271|1\cdots 1$ ($120$ ones).

Comment: @peter that really looks interesting, only if you could make it a bit clearer, you see I've never heard of these theorems before.

Comment: Fermat's little theorem states : If $p$ is a prime not dividing $a$, then $p$ divides $a^{p-1}-1$

Comment: I'm not getting a thing. Probably if you could write that in the English language rather than the mathematical symbols

Comment: Okay so what is a and p according to it in my question? Shouldn't a be 271 and p be the repunit?

Comment: We have $a=10$ and $p=271$ here. So, $271|10^{270}-1$. The rep-units are closely related to the numbers $10^n-1$ because we have $R_n=\frac{10^n-1}{9}$ , where $R_n=1\cdots 1$ with $n$ ones.

Answer (score 2):

$$\overbrace{11\ldots1}^{123 \text{ times}}= 10^3\sum_{i=0}^{23} (11111 \times 10^{5i})+111$$

$$11111 \equiv 0 \mod 271$$ (credit: Henry's hint)

Hence $$10^3\sum_{i=0}^{23} (11111 \times 10^{5i})+111 \equiv 0 + 111 \equiv 111 \mod 271$$

Comment: How did you figure out that 271x41 is 11111 and were you looking for it when you just started to solve the question?

Comment: @peter did a great job in explaining. I am an amateur.  I wrote a small program to find such thing http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user42_qdzAOcB9Jo_0.py

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh Thank you very much!

Comment: @Zlatan I hope I could shed light on this stuff.

Comment: You did a great job peter. I'm glad I had you to answer all my questions. Hey still according it that little theorem 271 should divide 111..123 times (raised to the power 270) -1.. So is it okay to right $10^270$ instead of my rep unit?

Comment: repeating units can be written as $\sum_{i=0}^{122} 10^i$. I think there is a maths display problem to understand your previous question. $10^{270}$ is not equal to the repetition of $1$ though.