# Find the remainder when $\overbrace{11\ldots1}^{124 \text{ times}}$ is divided by 271 .

Tags: number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

We have to find the remainder when $\overbrace{11\ldots1}^{124 \text{ times}}$ is divided by 271 .

In this I thought of using chinese remainder theorem or congruency/modular arithmetic .

But I could not get any good start .

I found a similar question .

[What will be the remainder when 111...(123 times) is divided by 271?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2069150/what-will-be-the-remainder-when-111-123-times-is-divided-by-271)

[Finding the remainder of $\overbrace{11\ldots1}^{123 \text{ times}}$ divided by $271$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2009917/finding-the-remainder-of-overbrace11-ldots1123-text-times-divided-by)

But in that I could not understand how they got the idea that of 271x41

Comment: Please read the comments of the question you are duplicating. (In addition, your question has zero context.)

Answer (score 2):

The number in question is $a=(10^{124}-1)/9$.

We find $10^3\equiv187$, $10^4\equiv244$, $10^5\equiv 1\pmod{271}$.
Therefore $10^{124}\equiv 244\pmod{271}$. So $9a\equiv 243\pmod{271}$.
I'll leave solving this congruence to you...

Answer (score 0):

Since $11\,111=271\times41$, and since $111\,111=11\,111\times10+1$, $111\,111\equiv1\pmod{271}$. So $\overbrace{111\,111}^{6n\text{ times}}\equiv1\pmod{271}$. Since $124=6\times20+4$, $\overbrace{111\,111}^{124}\equiv1\,111\pmod{271}$, and $1\,111\equiv27\pmod{271}$.

Comment: Seing as how the last sentence of the question is "But in that I could not understand how they got the idea that of 271x41", I don't think this answer helps very much.